# What's wrong with this fragment of PHP code?

Tags: php

I'm writing some html+php code but this part seems to be causing error. Do you see something wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT p.seccio_id, count(*), sum(r.preu) 
FROM report r, persona p 
WHERE r.usuari_upc = p.persona_id 
and r.any = " . $_POST["any"] . " 
and r.mes = " . $_POST["mes"] . " 
and p.any_id = '" 
if ($_POST["mes"] < 9) echo ($_POST["any"] - 1) . "-" . $_POST["any"] . "'";
else echo $_POST["any"] "-" . ($_POST["any"] + 1) . "'";
"GROUP BY p.seccio_id
ORDER BY p.seccio_id";
```

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: anyway, `if` and `else` are not expressions, you can't concatenate them to strings.

Comment: The page doesn't get any result. Completely blank. I'm just asking if there's any syntax error in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Usually errors are logged to the web server's log, look there. Anyway, my point about string concatenation stands.

Comment: as @FedericoklezCulloca said, you can't do that with if/else statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split it up:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.seccio_id, count(*), sum(r.preu) FROM report r, persona p WHERE .usuari_upc = p.persona_id and r.any = " . $_POST["any"] . " and r.mes = " . _POST["mes"] . " and p.any_id = '";

if ($_POST["mes"] < 9)
    $sql .= ($_POST["any"] - 1) . "-" . $_POST["any"] . "'";
else
    $sql .= $_POST["any"] "-" . ($_POST["any"] + 1) . "'";

$sql .= " GROUP BY p.seccio_id ORDER BY p.seccio_id";
```

P.S. Your sql is vulenarable to SQL injection.

Comment: Watch out for sql injections.